# Intellij jrebel.log - Not watchable file CHANGE

Tags: intellij-idea, jrebel

I am using jrebel plugin for Intellij 2016.3 EAP and dont know why lines like these:

```
INFO  [22] [IntelliJFSNotify] Not watchable file CHANGE C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\ATI\ACE\Profiles.xml

INFO  [22] [IntelliJFSNotify] Not watchable file CHANGE C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\Skype\***\config.xml
```

are printed in jrebel.log since those paths are not within my project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRebel needs to monitor filesystem to detect class changes. While it generally picks up changes only from directories listed in `rebel.xml` and logs them for debugging purposes (e.g. if something didn't reload, did we even detect the change?), it's trivial to log changes of all directories. It's done also to speed up investigation in support, to help users configure their `rebel.xml`.